# Getting "Error: Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout"

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1. Whenever I drag button or do any other activity on my Activity Screen it gives me the following error

> Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout"

[image]

I need a permanent fix for this issue. Please help me.

Comment: Follow the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-a-constraint

Comment: I already dragged ConstraintLayout from Palette window and placed it in activity screen but it still shows me error

Comment: I solved this issue by my own anyway thanks for it

Comment: How about letting others know **how** you solved it and mark this as resolved? This could help others with the same issue. Otherwise your question is essentially worthless for SO.

Answer (score 20):

See in the pallete just above your design you will see a wand type tool, when you will hover over it it will show infer constraint , just click on it and your problem will be solved

Comment: Magical answer.

Comment: The best answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to the text view in your .xml file hover the cursor to the Error part(Red Underline) and Press (Alt + Enter) it will show you to automatically add the missing things select that and it will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file, in the xml code of your button, try adding the below code:
`tools:ignore="missingConstraints"`

**Or else:**
When you click the button in the design, it shows four circles at the top, bottom, left and right. Drag those four circles to the alternate four circles of the screen. This is done for alignment.